# Are all "on'yomi" monosyllabic?

Tags: kanji, readings

I think that the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji) for "kanji" has an error.

Please look at the last sentence in the third paragraph underneath the "kun'yomi" heading. quote:
 "...*This contrasts with on'yomi, **which are monosyllabic**, and is unusual*..."

My understanding is that none of "しゃく"、"ちょく"、"にゃく"、.... are monosyllabic.

If I am correct about this, can someone with greater standing than mine make the appropriate change to the "kanji" Wikipedia entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're borrowings of monosyllabic morphemes from Chinese.  But when sounds are borrowed from one language into another, they typically have to conform to the phonology of the target language.  At some point between their initial borrowings and now, these morphemes have had to adapt to the rules of how sounds are put together in modern Japanese.

And in modern Japanese, the only permissible syllable codas are:

1. The moraic nasal (as in 漢字 `/kaN.zi/`).
2. The first consonant of a geminate pair (as in 日光 `/nik.koː/`).

So any coda that didn't fit these rules had to bend: either it had to be dropped, or it had to become part of a separate syllable.  Of course, this separate syllable needed its own nucleus, so a vowel had to be inserted, often either `/u/` or `/i/`.

For example, according to [the Baxter-Sagart reconstructions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aBaxter-Sagart_Old_Chinese_reconstruction) the Old Chinese reading of 息 was `*sək`, which is quite similar to the modern Japanese *on'yomi* `/soku/`—except, of course, for the added vowel at the end, which makes it not one but two syllables long!

As a result of this sort of adaptation, not every *on'yomi* in Japanese is one syllable.  Many are two syllables instead.  (While this isn't the only change that *on'yomi* have undergone over the years, discussing this change alone is sufficient to demonstrate that they're not all monosyllabic.  We can gloss over the exact set of historical changes and still make our point.)

Here's one possible way to classify the current set of *on'yomi*:

#### Monomoraic, monosyllabic on'yomi

> ア イ ウ エ オ カ ガ キ ギ キャ ギャ キョ ギョ ク グ ケ ゲ コ ゴ サ ザ シ ジ シャ ジャ シュ ジュ ショ ジョ ス ズ セ ゼ ソ タ ダ チ チュ チョ ツ テ デ ト ド ナ ニ ニャ ニュ ニョ ヌ ノ ハ バ ヒ ビ フ ブ ベ ホ ボ マ ミ ム メ モ ヤ ユ ヨ ラ リ リュ リョ ル ロ ワ

#### Bimoraic, monosyllabic on'yomi

> アン イン ウン エイ エン オウ オン カン ガン キュウ ギュウ キョウ ギョウ キン ギン クウ グウ クン グン ケイ ゲイ ケン ゲン コウ ゴウ コン ゴン シイ サン ザン シュウ ジュウ シュン ジュン ショウ ジョウ シン ジン スウ スン セイ ゼイ セン ゼン ソウ ゾウ ソン タン ダン チャン チュウ チュン チョウ チン ツウ テイ テン デイ デン トウ ドウ トン ドン ナン ニュウ ニョウ ニン ネイ ネン ノウ ノン ハン バン ヒュウ ビュウ ヒョウ ビョウ ヒン ビン フウ フン ブン ヘイ ベイ ヘン ベン ホウ ボウ ホン ボン マン ミュウ ミョウ ミン メイ メン モウ モン ユウ ヨウ ラン リュウ リョウ リン レイ レン ロウ ロン ワン

#### Bimoraic, bisyllabic on'yomi

> アイ アク アツ イウ イキ イク イシ イチ イツ ウツ エキ エツ オク オツ カイ ガイ カク ガク カチ ガチ カツ ガツ キク キケ キチ キツ キャク ギャク キョク ギョク クツ ケキ ゲキ ケチ ケツ ゲツ コク ゴク コツ コチ サイ ザイ サク サツ ザツ ジカ シキ ジキ ジク シチ シツ ジツ シャク ジャク シュク ジュク シュツ ジュツ ショク ジョク スイ ズイ スク セキ セク セチ セツ ゼツ ソク ソチ ソツ ゾク タイ ダイ タク ダク タチ タツ ダツ チキ チク チツ チャク チュツ チョク ツイ ツク テキ デキ テツ デツ トク ドク トツ ナイ ナツ ニク ニチ ニャク ネツ ハイ ハク ハチ ハツ バイ バク バチ バツ ヒキ ヒチ ヒツ ヒャク ヒョク ビャク フキ フク フツ ブツ ヘキ ベキ ヘツ ベツ ホク ボク ボチ ホツ ボツ マイ マク マチ マツ ミツ ミャク メツ モク モチ モツ ヤク ユイ ヨク ライ ラク ラチ ラツ リキ リク リツ リャク リュク リョク ルイ レキ レツ ロク ワイ ワク ワツ

Of course, if you reject this definition of syllable and instead use syllable as a synonym for mora, then you can relabel the middle category "Bimoraic, bisyllabic on'yomi", but either way the result is the same: all *on'yomi* are either one or two syllables long.

The above chart isn't the only possible way to classify the modern set of *on'yomi*—see comments for some discussion.  But no matter how you do it, unless you reject the notion of syllable entirely, you're going to end up with some *on'yomi* being bisyllabic.

So in short, you're correct: they aren't all monosyllabic.

Comment: I realize that these things can be analyzed in different ways, but I believe that the common analysis is that e.g. アイ is one syllable. Do you have sources that claim otherwise?

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure about that.  I've just been reading conflicting opinions about whether Japanese has diphthongs (it seems to be a controversial point!) and thought that if it doesn't, then the vowel pairs should be the nuclei of separate syllables, so I stuck them in the third category.  I'm now away from my computer but I'll be able to revisit this answer tomorrow--any further thoughts?

Comment: I've been wondering about the necessity of a distinction between morae and syllables in Japanese. You might be interested in the question I asked at linguistics.stackexchange some time ago: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/is-the-concept-of-syllables-pronunciation-relevant-in-languages-with-mora-based

Comment: There was a point where /m/ and /t/ were also allowed as syllable codas, cf. 連声 phenomena.